# Prolog: Make functor term from elements of a list

Tags: prolog

I need to give a list to a predicate and get back from it a term containing the elements of that list.

So I would have something like:

```
turn_into_struct(+List, -Term).
```

One thing that I did think about is to use `nb_setarg/3` recursively for each element of the list, but this way I would need to instantiate the term with a specific arity and I couldn't find how to do that.

Comment: Is this homework?  (If so then I'll avoid giving too much away :-)

Comment: Yes, it is homework, but it is a specific, language-related question.

Comment: Well, I suppose the question is, are you allowed to just reuse `=..`, or is your homework to recreate something that does the same job using other predicates?

Comment: The homework is more complex. You didn't spoil anything, I can assure you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the length of the list first, construct the new term with dummy values, and then populate each argument either recursively or through backtracking (using `findall`, for instance).  I'll fill in additional details if you need them (and as long as I'm not spoiling your own effort).

```
length(List, Len),
functor(Struct, struct, Len),
% Fill in each argument of Struct here...
```

There is a simpler one-line technique using SWI-Prolog's `=..` predicate, though.

Comment: `=..` did the trick, thanks. The `functor` predicate is nice to know, also.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to create a term from a list is to use [=..](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2) (aka "Univ").  For example,

```
turn_into_struct(List, Struct) :-
    Struct =.. [structure|List].
```

The proper terminology for "struct" in the original question is "term".

(Univ is mentioned in comments on other answers, but I'm reposting it as an answer for posterity and greater visibility)